# When statically linking a library, getting Linker error : cannot find -lgcc_s

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++, static-linking

I want to statically link a library say libcurl. As both static and shared libraries are in same folder, I am using -Wl,-Bstatic to let the linker know to use static library.

```
g++ -o prog prog.o -Wl,-Bstatic -lcurl.
```

But above command is giving error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
```

If I exclude  -Wl,-Bstatic, it works fine, but It will use shared library which I dont want.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Do you know g++ is C++ compiler not C compiler?

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. But what is your point? I checked -Bstatic option in man page of g++

Comment: Well you removed the C tag now, the point is you tagged this question to C, I pointed out to remove the tag that is not relevant to the question so that you won't get unnecessary downvotes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use the `g++` front-end to perform your linkage, like:

```
g++ -o prog prog.o -Wl,-Bstatic -lcurl
```

`g++` invokes the linker passing it your linkage options and also silently
adding to the linker commandline a large number of boiler-plate options that
are invariant for C++ linkage.

For example, your C++ program very probably will need to link the standard C++ library,
`libstdc++`, but your `g++` command doesn't mention it. It certainly also needs the standard C library,
but it isn't mentioned either. `g++` automatically adds linkage options to link these and
other libraries.

You can see all the boilerplate that `g++` adds to your linkage by running it in
verbose mode. You will see the like of:

```
$ g++ -v -o prog prog.o -Wl,-Bstatic -lcurl
...
...
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'prog' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/liblto_plugin.so \
 -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper \
 -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cckwrJp6.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s \
 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc \
 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc \
 --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu \
 --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -z now -z relro \
 -o prog /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbeginS.o \
 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu \
 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
 -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib \
 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../.. prog.o \
 -Bstatic -lcurl -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc \     
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtendS.o \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note in particular your `-Bstatic` option and the following linkage options:

```
 -Bstatic -lcurl -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc \     
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtendS.o \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

which include your `-lcurl` and also the default system libraries:

```
-lcurl -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc
```

Then see the [documentation of the `-Bstatic` linker option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.29/ld/Options.html):

> -Bstatic
>
> ...
>
> Do not link against shared libraries. This is only meaningful on platforms for which shared libraries are supported.
>   The different variants of this option are for compatibility with various systems.
>   You may use this option multiple times on the command line: **it affects library searching for -l options which follow it.**
>   This option also implies --unresolved-symbols=report-all. This option can be used with -shared.
>   Doing so means that a shared library is being created but that all of the library’s external
>   references must be resolved by pulling in entries from static libraries.

[my emphasis]

So, your `-Bstatic` option directs the linker to link *static* versions of:

```
-lcurl -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc
```

It finds the static `libcurl.a` that you have installed. It fails to find a
static library for `-lgcc_s` because there isn't any `libgcc_s.a` installed on
your system. You just have dynamic versions of this and other basic system libraries,
which is pretty normal.

If you want the linker to link static libraries *only* for the `-l` options that *you*
specify, then you must turn on `-Bstatic` before your `-l` options *and turn it off
after them*, `-Bdynamic`, even if this makes `-Bdynamic` the last thing on your commandline.
Because `g++` (or any other GCC front-end, `gcc`, `gfortran`...) is going to add `-l`
options to your commandline behind the scenes. Link like:

```
g++ -o prog prog.o -Wl,-Bstatic -lcurl -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

to fix this particular linkage error.